AWS Glue: Selecting specific columns from SQL Query
I have setup a AWS Glue job using pyspark code(spark.sql(query)) to run SQL code, but as AWS glue instead of taking selected column, considering all the columns and due to this I am getting an error for the columns where I dont have privileges to access them.
Please let me know if there is an alternative to avoid these issues using AWS glue.
